# Find a URL's unspecified Index page

Tags: python, html, url, indexing, http-headers

Just wondering if you guys know if it possible to find a websites index page. A lot of URL's e.g "www.google.com" don't explicitly specify the URL it's loading. A lot of pages use what's called an index page so users don't need to specify the direct files. Does anybody know of any way to get the name of this index page, via HTTP Requests or anything really.

Comment: If I may be so bold... **why?!**

Comment: @deceze I am trying to save the html files. How would I get the filename?

Comment: As pointed out below, there *isn't* a filename. Name the file `www.google.com.html` or something.

Comment: For the general case most web servers use default index file pages, is there a way to obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

"www.google.com" *is* the URL you're loading. A URL is not a reference to a file. It is entirely irrelevant what kind of file structure may be on a web server. A web server is an application which responds to HTTP requests. This response does not have to be backed by a file at all. Google most certainly doesn't serve anything from the file system; instead its front HTTP servers hold the necessary HTML response *in memory* and serve it as quickly as possible from there as HTTP response.

Having a "default index file" is merely a default configuration of many web servers, because it's easy. But web servers and URLs have nothing intrinsically to do with files on disk at all. The answer to your question is [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question).